# Symfony2 related entities are not available when they are initially created

Tags: symfony

I have 2 Entities with a OneToMany relationship

```
class Surgery implements SurgeryInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Incompass\SurgeryBundle\Entity\Tray", mappedBy="surgery", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $trays;

    ...
}

class Tray implements TrayInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Incompass\SurgeryBundle\Entity\Surgery", inversedBy="trays")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="surgery_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $surgery;

    ...
}
```

These entities and their services / handlers have been working fine. I've recently added a new field to surgery so I can get the number of trays in a surgery without getting all the tray records, and added a function to the entity that I can call when ever trays are added / removed

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 */
protected $num_trays;

...

    /**
 * Update num_trays
 *
 * @return Surgery
 */
public function updateNumTrays()
{
    $trays = $this->getTrays();

    $this->setNumTrays(count($trays));

    return $this;
}
```

This works everywhere but during a RESTful POST. For some reason when I create a new surgery, and add trays to it, the trays don't exist properly. I actually have my POST split up into 2 requests, the first creates the surgery, the second creates the trays.

In the second POST I have this code (this is simplified to the relevant code)

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$surgery = $entityManager->getRepository('IncompassSurgeryBundle:Surgery')->find($id);
$trays = $request->request->get('add_trays');
$this->get('incompass_surgery.surgery.service')->addRemoveTrays($surgery, $trays);
$entityManager->flush();

$surgery->updateNumTrays();
```

The addRemoveTrays() function is working, I can see the new trays in the database.
The updateNumTrays() function is setting num_trays to 0 when I first try to create the trays, if trays already exist it creates new trays and returns the new total.

For example, if my request has add_trays as 2. Then the first time I POST it, it creates 2 trays, but updateNumTrays() sets num_trays to 0. If I POST the request again, it creates 2 more trays, and updateNumTrays() set num_trays to 4.

I added this at the end of the function

```
// Get updated Surgery
$surgery2 = $entityManager->getRepository('IncompassSurgeryBundle:Surgery')->find($id);
var_dump(count($surgery2->getTrays()));
$trays = $entityManager->getRepository('IncompassSurgeryBundle:Tray')->findBy(array('surgery' => $id));
var_dump(count($trays));
```

If the request had add_trays set to 2, the output is:

0

2

Why is the surgery that I get from the repository not able to get its trays properly? I'm especially confused as the Tray repository can find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured this out. I needed to detach the surgery from the entity manager then get a new copy of it:

```
$entityManager->flush();
$entityManager->detach($surgery);
$surgery = $entityManager->getRepository('IncompassSurgeryBundle:Surgery')->find($id);
$surgery->updateNumTrays();
```